# Django Get POST id before assignment to database

Tags: python, django

views.py

```
class Post(CreateView):
    fields = ('title', 'desc')
    model = models.Post

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save(commit=False)
        self.object.desc = self.object.id <---- 
        self.object.save()

        return super(ModelFormMixin, self).form_valid(form)
```

how to get object id from post before assignment? iam trying use `self.object.id` but return `none`

Comment: Generally the database will assign a primary key when the object is saved. Why do you need it before that time?

Comment: I think you are looking for [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/signals/#pre-save) signal.

Comment: as @Chris said you cannot have `id` before saving the object into databasae.

Comment: `self.object = form.save(commit=True)` ?

Comment: change order of  object.save() and object.desc

Comment: ah got it. @Chris i have scheme, when submit data to `Foo`, i need update other model like `bar` related to that database so i need that `id`.

Comment: Then as @abdul_niyas_pm suggests you should probably try using a signal. Right now your question is too abstract to provide a good answer, but if you [edit] it with some details about the two models we may be able to provide an answer.